# How to add value to ng-model in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

How to add value to ng-model in angularjs. my html is:

```
<textarea rows="5" ng-model="comment.comment_text"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" ng-model="comment.task_id" value="{{task.id}}">
<input type="hidden" ng-model="comment.user_id" value="{{profile.id}}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="create(comment)">Send</button>
```

and angular controller:

```
$scope.create = function(comment) {
     console.log(comment);
};
```

when click on button show result in console:

```
{comment_text: "test"}
```

BUT I want to show like this:

```
{comment_text: "test", user_id:1 ,task_id:53}
```

Comment: No, I want to set default value for `comment.user_id`

Answer (score 2):

On your controller's constructor you should definitely instantiate the initial value of your 'comment' variable using:

```
$scope.comment = $scope.comment || {
     user_id: 'amcpanaligan',
     comment_text: 'sample'
     //// other object property declaration goes here...
};
```

Comment: I think add `ng-init="comment.task_id = task.id"` to html is better than, but because `task.id` load after multi second it's doesn't work. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Why does loading task.id takes multi second? Where do you get it? If you are using a promise consider using the 'then' block of your promise.

Comment: Yes I use promise, I fetch `task.id` from database and I should wait for multi millisecond

Comment: So you are using some service or something that uses angular's $http or $resource service. You can initially set the values of some variables in your constructor and do something like $scope.comment.task_id = task.id on your promise's 'then' block

Answer (score 1):

`value={{someValue}}` does not make sense.
You should use only ng-model for text input hidden

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.task = {
    id: 1
  }
  $scope.create = function(comment) {
    comment.taskId = $scope.task.id;
    console.log(comment);

  };
}


<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <textarea rows="5" ng-model="comment.comment_text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="task.id">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="create(comment)">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x75cn978/)

Comment: I want to add default value to `comment.user_id` in html

Comment: Thanks, I think add `ng-init="comment.task_id = task.id"` to html is better than, but because `task.id` load after multi second it's doesn't work. Do you have any suggestion?